# Method that takes Input from user in C#

Tags: c#, methods, pass-by-reference

I'm switching to C# from C++ and I'm trying to learn the methods. Can you help me create a method that takes 2 variables as input from the user? In C++ it was pretty easy just making a void method and adding `&` before the variable's name like: `void Input( int &a, int &b)` which would save any changes in their value in the main function. Is there a way to do that in C#?

Comment: The `&` is a `ref` in C#.

Comment: or use Tuple https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @brykneval: a tuple is read-only afaik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# you have two options for `T &x` of C++:

- **`ref` parameters** - these have the same capabilities as C++ reference parameters, and
- **`out` parameters** - these allow passing data back from a method, but not into the method.

In your case, `out` is more appropriate, because it lets you pass variables that have not been previously assigned:

```
void Input( out int a, out int b) {
    ... // Read and assign a and b
}
```

You can call this method like this:

```
// In C# 7
Input(out int a, out int b);    
// Prior to C# 7
int a, b;
Input(out a, out b);
```

Note that unlike C++ where taking reference is automatic, C# requires you to mark it with the keyword `out`.

Comment: For out the parameter must be assigned a value before the function member completes normally.

Comment: Is `out` the right answer for OP's problem? He mentions that he wants to change variables from user input, which would implicate that the variables are already assigned. Hence, `out` would not work and `ref` should be used?

Comment: @brykneval right, that's exactly what should happen in a method that performs input.

Comment: @NuclearPenguin I'm pretty sure that's an unfortunate choice of wording: C++ has no concept of `out` variables, so if you pass something by pointer or by reference, it's always a "change", not an initial assignment. C# gives you flexibility to decide whether you want the original value or not. A side effect of having `ref` would be the need to assign variables prior to making the call.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [ref (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx). This is equal to the C++ & references.

An example:

```
class RefExample
{
    static void Method(ref int i)
    {
        // The following statement would cause a compiler error if i
        // were boxed as an object.
        i = i + 44;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        int val = 1;
        Method(ref val);
        Console.WriteLine(val);

        // Output: 45
    }
}
```

Worth to mention that the usage of `ref` in C# should be pretty rare unlike in C++. Please refer to [Jon Skeet's](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html) article about parameter passing.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can **pass an argument by reference** with the **[`ref` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)**. So you can define your method like:

```
public void Input (ref int foo, ref int bar) {
    foo = 14;
    bar = 25;
}
```

You **call the method with the `ref` keyword** as well:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
Input(ref a, ref b);
// now a = 14 and b = 25
```

You this mention pass-by-reference explicitly (but the advantage is that syntactically it is clear that this is pass-by-reference).